# Is this BubbleSort sorting array from min to max or from max to min?

Tags: java, pseudocode

Question is, if this code sort array from **min** to **max** or from **max** to **min**, because I cannot figure it out.

This is just **pseudo-code**.

*'a' is array of **integers***

```
for (int i = n; i>=2; i--) {
   for (int j = 2; j>=i; j++) { 
      if (a[j-1] > a[j]) { swap( a[j-1], a[j] ); }
   }
}
```

Also when I tried to replace swap and run it with this code:

```
int temp = a[j-1];
a[j-1] = a[j];
a[j] = a[j-1];
```

I got error that index is out of bounds.

Thank you for answering my question or giving explanation.

***Edit:***

This question was on exam so that is why I asked for explanation. This code is not functional!

Comment: Did you try to run your code and see what it does?

Comment: Yes, I tried, I wrote that and also when I fixed out of bounds error and still I think it does nothing at all, but this was question on exam and I don't understand it.

Comment: The code presented in the question is buggy.  Not only the inner loop's termination condition but also both loops' lower bounds are wrong.  (Remember that Java arrays are indexed from 0, not from 1.)  The code, as written, *does not* sort the array, so the question posed is moot.  If you have reproduced the problem accurately then perhaps it was a trick question, but I'm guessing that you did not reproduce it accurately.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know how indexing is working for Java but I think teacher absolutely did mistake there, I am not sure. Thank you for response.

Answer (score 0):

In this line 2 of the code is creating problem.
j >=i and j++ will go on increasing there is no bound to this for loop and array has limited limited set of values after that it shows this error.

Answer (score -1):

The implementation of your for loop is not correct. If you are trying to implement a simple bubble sort, i would suggest trying this code. Use it as a guide.

```
  void bubbleSort(int arr[]) 
 { 
    int n = arr.length; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
            { 
                // swap arr[j+1] and arr[j] 
                int temp = arr[j]; 
                arr[j] = arr[j+1]; 
                arr[j+1] = temp; 
            } 
}
```